# Uncaught reference error - is not defined - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, requirejs

I've been reading up on requirejs for Magento 2 and I've used it sucessfully for some scripts but I'm having trouble with one called [Lity](https://sorgalla.com/lity/).

I have my `requirejs-config.js` file setup as follows:

```
var config = {
deps: [
    "js/main",
],

map: {
    '*': {
        'lityLightbox': 'js/lity',
    }
},
"shim": {
    "lityLightbox": ["jquery"],
}
};
```

and my `main.js` contains the following:

```
require(['jquery', 'lityLightbox'],
function ($, lityLightbox) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(document).on('click', '[data-lightbox]', lity);
    });
});
```

However I get the following console error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: lity is not defined` but yet the script still works but only sometimes?

How can I sort out the console error please? Is it anything to do with the order that the scripts are loaded?

## Update

After passing the reference correctly I now have a different error

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ($) { return factory(window, $); }'
```

This is on the first line of the [lity.js file](https://github.com/jsor/lity/blob/master/src/lity.js)

I have this entire script wrapped in `require(['jquery', 'lityLightbox'], function($){ *** });`

Are you able to help wth that too please

Comment: try with $(document).on('click', '[data-lightbox]', lityLightbox);

Comment: Omg I knew it would be something so stupidly simple. Can't believe I missed that, thank you mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to pass your object in your function as lityLightbox.**

You have passed lity instead of lityLightbox.

```
require(['jquery', 'lityLightbox'],
function ($, lityLightbox) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(document).on('click', '[data-lightbox]', lityLightbox);
    });
});
```

**Update**

```
var config = {
    deps: [
        "js/main",
    ],
    paths: {
        'lityLightbox': 'js/lity',      
    },
    "shim": {
        "lityLightbox": ["jquery"],
    }
};
```

Run deployment command.

Comment: Sorry to bring this back up again but I have a different error now. I've updated my question above with the details. Are you able to help with that too please?

Comment: Hmm that seems to have messed up the paths for my scripts. It is now trying to get them all from the theme root instead of theme_name/web/js/

What is the difference between paths and map?

Comment: check link,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216580/requirejs-paths-vs-map/25199309#25199309